# splash screen doesn't disappear when i launch the app for the first time

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an ionic app with a splash screen. When I install an app for the first time or when I clear app data, the splash screen does not disappear after launch. I always have to close the app, empty the memory and relaunch it and then everything is fine for the next time I launch the app.
The console does not show any bugs and I don't know what the problem may be. I'm trying to increase the splash screen duration but it still doesn't work.

Angular version: 13.0.1
ionic version: 5.36.0
capacitor version: 4.0.0

Comment: Do you have any condition on splash screen before redirecting user inside the app ?

Comment: no , i use the method ready of the plugin platform (platForm.ready().then(()=>{//hide splash screen}) )

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine in my project on Capacitor 3 to 4 (4.7) and Angular 13 to 15

```
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';
import { SplashScreen } from '@capacitor/splash-screen';

//Injected in root service
constructor() {
  SplashScreen.hide()
}

// or init this in App.component constructor or ngOnInit

App.addListener('appStateChange',() => {
(state: AppState) => {
      if (state.isActive) {
         Capacitor.isNativePlatform() && SplashScreen.hide();
      }
    }
})
```